# How to get HDMI audio on RX 480?

Tags: drivers, sound, hdmi, amd-graphics

My RX 480 is not working well with Ubuntu 16.04.2. I finished the installation yesterday and since then I do not have audio over HDMI. I've tried several options among them I upgraded Mesa, tried the AMD GPU Pro. Nothing is solving my problem. The other issue that I have is when I use the AMD GPU Pro the monitor linked over HDMI will just turn black only the monitor using the DP port is working. I am wondering if this is an issue related to Ubuntu if so what is the best distro for the RX480?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out the kernel recommended here?
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-AMDGPU-DC-Kernel

I had no audio over HDMI on with my RX 480 on ubuntu 16+. After installing the kernel with AMDGPU DC/DAL it all worked perfectly